# Jenkins "Build Triggers" shows UTC instead of local or server timezone

Tags: jenkins

When configuring jobs to run periodically, Jenkins is showing UTC time.  I expect Jenkins to show the timezone as America/New_York.

[image: Build Triggers shows UTC timezone]

Jenkins version 2.121.2 is configured to run using timezone America/New_York as described in this article https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Change+time+zone

I've confirmed this by looking at the java process and I can see the option passed

```
jenkins    1706  7.1 79.5 16210100 12923272 ?   Ssl  May11 8541:26 /etc/alternatives/java -XX:+UseG1GC -Xms1g -Xmx12g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -Dhudson.tasks.MailSender.SEND_TO_UNKNOWN_USERS=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dorg.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone=America/New_York -DJENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins -jar -Dcb.distributable.name=RedHat / Fedora RPM -Dcb.distributable.commit_sha=888f01a54c12cfae5c66ec27fd4f2a7346097997 /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war --logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080 --httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1 --debug=5 --handlerCountMax=100 --handlerCountMaxIdle=20
```

I can also see the option in http://server/systemInfo
[image: java option systeminfo]

And the user.timezone is also set to America/New_York
[image]

The server is configured to use America/New_York timezone as well:

```
# ls -lAF /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 38 Jan  7  2018 /etc/localtime -> ../usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York

# date
Thu Aug  2 15:01:36 EDT 2018
```

idk if it matters, but Jenkins is using OpenJDK:

```
/etc/alternatives/java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_161"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b14, mixed mode)
```

I expect that the 'Schedule' box would show the server timezone or my timezone, not UTC.

Comment: I have the exact same situation -- was this ever answered or did you figure out the solution yourself? This is an old question so I'm sure you either figured it out or just gave up, but I'd be interested in the end of the story either way.

Comment: Didn't figure this one out.  It still shows UTC in the web UI.

Answer (score 2):

I got this working finally by setting BOTH (it didnt work without the user one):

- `-Dorg.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone=America/New_York`
- `-Duser.timezone=America/New_York`

Since I run in Docker, my full command line (maybe useful to someone) is here:

`docker run --name=jenkins -td -p 5000:5000 -p 80:8080 -v $HOME/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -e "JAVA_OPTS=-server -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xloggc:\$JENKINS_HOME/gc-%t.log -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:GCLogFileSize=20m -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintGCCause -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintReferenceGC -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:G1SummarizeRSetStatsPeriod=1 -Xms5120m -Xmx10240m -Dhudson.model.ParametersAction.keepUndefinedParameters=true -Dorg.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone=America/New_York -Duser.timezone=America/New_York" jenkins/jenkins:2.164.3`

This takes into some performance tuning stuff found at https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/11/21/gc-tuning/